# OSX equivalent for IP_RECVERR

Tags: c, linux, macos, network-programming, traceroute

I'm trying to port a TraceRoute program from Linux to OSX, and i'm having trouble finding the IP_RECVERR equivalent.

The way most people do the packet parsing is:

```
setsockopt (sock, IPPROTO_IPV4, IP_RECVERR, &on, sizeof (on))
```

And then when the packet comes in do something along the lines of:

```
sock_extended_err* err = nullptr;
for (cmsghdr* cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg); cmsg; cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsg)) {
  switch (cmsg->cmsg_level) {
    case IPPROTO_IPV4:
      if (cmsg->cmsg_type == IP_RECVERR) {
        err = (sock_extended_err*)CSMSG_DATA(cmsg);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

There also isn't an sock_extended_err on OSX which is problematic. I really just need to know if have had an error, and where the error originated.

Comment: On `OS X` the closest thing (that is built-in) would likely be `SO_ERROR`.

Comment: It doesn't look like it has a "TTL got to 0" error.

Comment: When you're using `IP_RECVERR` what type of value does it return? If you want to get the actual `TTL` value you'll have to use something like `getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &errcode, &len);`

Comment: Well, if you get a `IP_RECVERR`, you get the `sock_extended_err` struct, which you can then do things like `err->ee_origin == SO_EE_ORIGIN_ICMP` to see if the error came from the final destination.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct C equivalent in Mac OS X.  There might be something in the Mac-specific (or Objective-C) APIs, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: I'll do the manual packet parsing and post the answer here for the next poor soul.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but OS X is not supporting extended `IP_RECVERR` socket capabilities.

You can use: `#ifdef IP_RECVERR`to make it build on OS X where RECVERR/ERRQUEUE don't exist.

But if you are looking for that particular code execution, I think you have to port `IP_RECVERR` socket capability & `MSG_ERRQUEUE` in mac OS X. Thats sound like "I got new things to play". Happy coding.

Comment: Though this doesn't solve the problem, I'm not going to let that bounty go to waste!